# Handling multiple IoResult errors

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to send multiple values to a file / socket / some kind of writer. Each of those writes results in `IoResult`. How can I handle a whole batch of values nicely in that case? `Result` provides `.and_then(...)`, but that makes the code look really ugly. Is there a better way than this?

```
return
    writer.write(thing1).and_then(|()| {
    writer.write(thing2).and_then(|()| {
    ...
    writer.write(thing10)
    })})})})})})})})})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `try!` macro will help you here:

```
try!(writer.write(thing1))
try!(writer.write(thing2))
...
try!(writer.write(thing10))
```

It's defined like [this](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html):

```
macro_rules! try(
    ($e:expr) => (match $e { Ok(e) => e, Err(e) => return Err(e) })
)
```